# Como passar URL dinamicamente utilizando o FeignClient Kotlin + SpringCloud

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin

No meu código onde busco uma lista de clientes de uma determinada empresa, porem de acordo com o nome do cliente eu deve fazer a busca em um determinado EndPoint de terceiro.
No meu exemplo(abaixo) venha no get o nomeCliente = "compania-A" tenho que efetuar a busca no Endpoint "https://companiaA" caso venha nomeCliente = "compania-B" devo buscar no EndPoint "https://companiaB" e assim por diante, a mudança ocorre apenas no dominio.
Já gostaria de agradecer previamente a atenção de todos. Obrigado

**OBS: Se necessário posso receber a url do cliente como parâmetro no controller**

INTERFACE FEIGN CLIENT

```
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*

@FeignClient(url = "https://clienteA", name = "TrazLista")
interface ListaClienteExt {

@GetMapping("/lista-cliente")
fun getListaCliente(@RequestParam(required = true) nomeCliente: String): ResponseEntity<Any>
```

}

CONTROLLER

```
fun getListaCliente(
    @RequestParam(required = true) nomeCliente: String
): ResponseEntity<Any> {
    try {
        val list = ListaClienteExt.getListaCliente(nomeCliente).body
        return ResponseEntity(list, HttpStatus.OK)
    } catch (e: FeignException) {
        return ResponseEntity(MessageJson(e.contentUTF8() ?: "Erro externo"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    } catch (e: ExceptionMessage) {
        return ResponseEntity(MessageJson(e.message ?: "Erro get"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a URL na anotação @FeignClient() pode ser dinâmica, normalmente se utiliza uma property no application.yml (properties), então a interface ficaria assim por exemplo:

```
// O parametro-host seria a sua url configurada por property (pode configurar qual vai ser por cliente em um dbconfig)**texto em negrito**
@FeignClient(url = "${parametro-host:http://localhost:8761}/clientes", name = "TrazLista")
interface ListaClienteExt {

@GetMapping("/lista-cliente")
fun getListaCliente(@RequestParam(required = true) nomeCliente: String): ResponseEntity<Any>
```

Mas se você quiser alterar o @GetMapping dinamicamente, eu acredito que não seja uma ideia muito boa, pois quem consultar seus clients terá o código apontado para esses endpoints, porém quem foi consultar esses clients deve ter a mesma config nas properties da aplicação.